# Titanium Mobile support for Windows Phone 8

Tags: titanium-mobile, windows-phone-8

Will Titanium Studio support the Windows Phone 8 platform? Is there any talk of it? Is there anything concrete from Titanium stating they are doing it?

I looked on google and can find nothing.

Comment: if google cant find it. Then no one ... well I havent heard anything about windows phone 8 from Appcelerator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently it is just iOS, Android, Blackberry and Tizen are supported by Titanium Appcelerator, though Blackberry is in beta with a paid subscription. You will get more updates and information from [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/05/major-titanium-updates.html) blog post.

**Edit : [Titanium Support Plans for Windows 8](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/01/titanium-support-plans-for-windows-8.html)**

**Update 1 : [windows-8-support-whats-going-on](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/01/windows-8-support-whats-going-on/)**

**Update 2 : [Getting Started with Windows 8 SDK](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Getting_Started_with_the_Windows_8_SDK)**

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for - from that blog you linked to: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/139441/windows-phone#answer-251988

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/01/titanium-support-plans-for-windows-8.html

Comment: Latest information: Windows 8 Support, What's Going On? - http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/01/windows-8-support-whats-going-on/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for platforms that are not supportive at a native level, you can still get your apps to work in the webview?