# Titanium Appcelerator support for Windows Mobile

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to venture into Hybrid app development by using Titanium Appcelerator.

I am targeting all major platforms including Windows Mobile. But after I have installed the Titanium Studio I found that there is no option available to build for Windows Mobile.

Does Titanium support Windows Mobile apps or is there any work around to build apps for Windows Mobile using appcelerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Titanium supports windows phone development.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Getting_Started_with_the_Windows_Phone_SDK-section-37538371_GettingStartedwiththeWindowsPhoneSDK-RunontheEmulator

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763518/titanium-mobile-support-for-windows-phone-8/13765379#13765379). Titanium currently not supporting Windows-8. But it plans for windows-8 support. You can refer [Titanium Support Plans for Windows 8](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/01/titanium-support-plans-for-windows-8.html) also.